# GraphQL with ASP.NET framework (and not .NET Core)

Tags: .net, graphql, github-graphql

I'm relatively new to GraphQL and want to implement GraphQL to my existing **ASP.NET Framework** (with Entity Framework 4) application which has an MSSQL Server as the backend.

While browsing for GraphQL libraries and for their demos/examples I found out that all the .NET related examples are using the relatively new **.NET Core** framework in their examples. (e.g. https://github.com/JacekKosciesza/StarWars)

I want to know whether referring to such examples is advisable for my **.NET Framework** project and if there are any examples for the same i.e. particularly specific to **.NET Framework**.

Comment: The *libraries* run in both *runtimes*. The examples will work the same. As for why people write their examples using .NET Core - they are writing about new tech like GraphQL, why would they use the *old* framework? Which is why .NET Core is the fourth most popular framework in SO's developer survey this year.

Comment: If you check the Package Manager images in the link you posted, it shows that the GraphQL targets both .NET Framework v 4.5+ *and* any framework that supports the [.NET Standard 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), ie  all Full Framework versions since 4.5, Mono, Xamarin, UWP, .NET Core. Even if it targeted eg .NET Standard 2.0, it would pull in any required compatibility libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. There are rarely any example of GraphQL using .NET framework. To answer your question I can say that, in my case I had to use GraphQL with .NET framework since I had other project dependencies which were already written in .NET framework. I guess similarly, you may ofcourse need GraphQL implementation in .NET framework. You also asked for an example. Here is one example that I have setup in Github (GraphQL server example in .NET framework). This is a very basic example and should be simple to try out. So here is my two cents who are looking for it. https://github.com/mail4hafij/GraphQL

Comment: How is graphql server registered in .net framework?